# PHP Exec with parameters and mysql insert

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to run a mysql insert query using php exec with parameters.

Exec Code:

```
exec("php exec.php $parameter1 >1.log &"); // I have a 1.log with 777
```

In Exec.php:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/functions/connection.php";

if($_REQUEST['parameter1']!="")
   $proxy_id=$_REQUEST['parameter1'];
else
   $proxy_id= $argv[1];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO proxy_log(proxy_id,last_used_time) VALUES($proxy_id,NOW())");
```

But nothing is happening when I am running this. Can anybody please help on this ?

Comment: SQL injection warning... `$_REQUEST['parameter1'] = "'; drop table students;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` isn't available in CLI mode. use an absolute path.

```
include "/your/absolute/path/functions/connection.php";
```

`$_REQUEST` isn't available either, your if statement will always go in the else part.